# XSD schema to JSON schema

Tags: java, json, xml, xsd

guys! I need to convert a XSD schema to JSON schema. I know there are tools already to do that, but what I need is something that converts to JSON schema without any data loss. What I mean is that...
For example

I want an easy way to access the tags and their properties like 'use="required"', 'maxOccurs="5"'

Also to be able to support all XSD features like when XSD has to pick an element in a pool of many elements (xs:choice I believe).

Any guides and tips are welcome. Java solution prefered. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert an XSD schema losslessly to a JSON schema because there are many features in XSD that have no equivalent in JSON-schema. For example, an XML vocabulary might allow a section element to comprise a heading followed by a sequence of paragraphs. The nearest JSON equivalent would be an array of objects in which the first object represents the heading and the subsequent objects represent paragraphs. XSD allows you to constrain the sequence to contain exactly one heading followed by one-or-more paragraphs. JSON schema has no corresponding construct, for the simple reason that no-one with any sense uses JSON to represent that kind of data.